# Create selectable pushpin in Bing maps (XAML)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, bing-maps

This is more of XAML question for silverlight.

```
<Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector 
                            m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}" 
                            ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, ElementName=MainMap}" 
                            Content="{Binding}">
                            <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DotTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding IsGPSDataRecent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGreenRedBrushConverter}}" StrokeThickness="1">
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayId}" />
                                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </Ellipse>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DotTemplate>
                            <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.NumberedTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{Binding IsGPSDataRecent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGreenRedBrushConverter}}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2" Height="20" CornerRadius="8">
                                        <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DisplayId}" />
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.NumberedTemplate>
                        </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector>
```

On XAML above I have 2 different templates based on map zoom level. When it is zoomed out - it shows smaller ellipse, when user zooms closer - I increase size of pushpin.

2 issues:

1. WIth a lot of pushpins it get's really slow, I beleive it's due to template selection.
2. I want it to be different. I want to create "IsSelected" property so all pushpins will be the same on all zoom levels but when user clicks on pushpin - it expands in size.

I wonder how do I code "selection" part. I want only one pushpin to be selected at time. I can bind to property and make pushpin parts visible/invisible but I'm not sure how to code "selection" piece. Should it be Button?

Answer (score 0):

When doing a windows phone app I had the issue of many pins causing "lag" the easiest way around that is to only show pins within a certain radius of the centre of the map and remove the others until they come into the radius.

Cheers
Mark